# Dart equivalent of Swift Integer closed range

Tags: dart, range

I have a use-case where I have a start and end value from Json and would like to be able to define a closed range between them. Coming from Swift, I would use the [Closed Integer Range](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange). This way, I can perform `contains()` functions on them as well as find the start and end values. I was wondering if there was an equivalent of this built into Dart? If not, what is the most efficient way of creating this? I would assume something with sets? Thank you in advance

Comment: Are there other operations you want to do?  If you just want to retrieve the start and end values and check if the range contains a single value, then it's trivial to make a class that provides a `bool contains(int value) => value >= start && value <= end;` method.

Comment: I have never used it, but perhaps try [`package:xrange`](https://pub.dev/packages/xrange) if you need additional functionality.